# LSTM keras - Value error how to resolve input dimension

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, dimensions

I have made a function for training data which pick random files either positive or negative. it is a binary classification problem.

```
    model=Sequential()
InputBatch = np.expand_dims(InputBatch, 0)
print(InputBatch.shape)
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(1,6,30),return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(InputBatch,PositiveOrNegativeLabel,batch_size=6,nb_epoch=10,verbose=1,validation_split=0.05)
```

the shape of InputBatch variable is (1,6,30)

for example my input data is

```
[[   nan  1520.  1295.    nan  8396.  9322. 12715.    nan  5172.  7232.
  11266.    nan 11266.  2757.  4416. 12020. 12111.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [   nan  3045. 11480.   900.  5842. 11496.  4463.    nan 11956.   900.
  10400.  8022.  2504. 12106.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [   nan  9307. 12003.  2879.  6398.  9372.  4614.  5222.    nan    nan
   2879. 10364.  6923.  4709.  4860. 11871.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [   nan  6689.  2818. 12003.  6480.    nan     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [   nan  3395.  1087. 11904.  7232.  8840. 10115.  4494. 11516.  7441.
   8535. 12106.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [   nan  1287.   420.  4070. 11087.  7410. 12186.  2387. 12111.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]
```

I have set the shape of data which is (6,30)

I am getting value error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_16_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1,6, 30)
```

**it is getting three dimension input i don't understand how and why**

Comment: Try passing the data in the format of `(None, 6, 32)`

Comment: letme try with this @Novak

Comment: @Novak not working i think i have to reshape my data into three dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSTM inputs have to be in `3 dimensional(samples,timesteps,features)`. And your data seems to be in 2D. You can use the `numpys reshape()` function to convert your data to 3D.

For example if you are using 1 time-step then you will have to reshape it as `array.reshape(6,1,30)` or if you are using 6 timestep then `array.reshape(1,6,30)`

For more information on reshaping input for LSTM you can check this [site](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/)

[[update]]
There are so many problems with your code

```
 model=Sequential()
InputBatch = np.expand_dims(InputBatch, 0)
print(InputBatch.shape)
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(1,6,30),return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(InputBatch,PositiveOrNegativeLabel,batch_size=6,nb_epoch=10,verbose=1,validation_split=0.05)
```

When  you convert your data to (1,6,30) you are basically saying that you have just one sample(only 1) ,batch_size is 6 but you have only 1 sample,you have only one sample but you are doing validation split.And since you have only one X value it will have only one Y ( PositiveOrNegativeLabel),So I have asisgneed just one value ie 1.

I have ran your program with the changes few changes with code and data that u have shown in the question (i changed NA to 0)  :

```
    a=np.array([ 
             [0,1520,1295,0,8396,9322,12715,0,5172,7232,11266,0,11266,2757,4416,12020,12111,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,3045,11480,900,5842,11496,4463,0,11956,900,10400,8022,2504,12106,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,9307,12003,2879,6398,9372,4614,5222,0,0,2879,10364,6923,4709,4860,11871,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,6689,2818,12003,6480,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,3395,1087,11904,7232,8840,10115,4494,11516,7441,8535,12106,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,1287,420,4070,11087,7410,12186,2387,12111,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
           ]
          )

PositiveOrNegativeLabel=np.array([[1]])
PositiveOrNegativeLabel=PositiveOrNegativeLabel.reshape(1,-1)
PositiveOrNegativeLabel.shape
InputBatch =InputBatch.reshape(1,6,30)
InputBatch.shape
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1,input_shape=(6,30)))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(InputBatch,PositiveOrNegativeLabel,batch_size=1,verbose=1)
```

Comment: can you make complete answer so that i can accept it

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra I have updated it.If you have any doubts you can clarify it.

Comment: its not working i have tried both array.reshape as well as np.expand_dims i get this error Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_33: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Comment: Can you paste the code where you have tried to reshape,,it seems your array has been reshaped as a 4D array and not 3D array. In array.reshape(6,1,30) i am assuming according to your example that there are just 6 samples and each sample has 30 features. While specifiying in LSTM layer you just have to mention the time step and the number of features ie input_shape=(1,30)

Comment: now when i am printing the shape i am getting (1,6,30)

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra I have updated the answer,there were quite a lot of problems with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182507/discussion-between-tayyab-gulsher-vohra-and-kerastf).

Comment: how to increase the number of samples in this example